# How can I extract string between two different strings in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

how can I extract word between two different symbols in Excel? It's all about this URL example: http://www.mywebsite.com/offers/spain/fuerterventura/hotel-x.html?lastminute

This function should be universal - I want to extract text between offers/ and / (offers/*/).

Comment: 2 questions : 1) what have you tried? 2) the link fails... A possible solution could use MID() and FIND() but without any example data....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your URL is in A2, try this...

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/",REPT(" ",LEN(A2))),LEN(A2)*4,LEN(A2)))
```

This will return "spain" from the example URL.